# Automatic logout using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: suspend, 22.04, logout

I'm experiencing random user logouts using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I don't want the system to automatically logout as this kills my running processes. Has anyone experienced similar issues and/or does anyone know how to prevent the automatic logouts from happening?

A detailed description (sorry if this is a little unstructured - I'm primarily a user and don't know a lot about how linux works):

- The logout never happened when I was actively working on the computer (I use it 4-5 days a week for 4~10 hours).
- When the automatic logout happens my screen is tinted red, this red tint does not occur when I manually logout (maybe graphics driver related issue? Why would this cause logout?).
- `last` shows this: `root  pts/x ipaddress date (00:00)`. I'm logged in as a regular user, not as root.
- logout happens at random times but usually it takes about half a day of idle time to happen

Things I have tried:

1. In power saving settings [I disabled automatic suspend](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-autosuspend.html.en)

   - additionally, I set the monitor to be always on (this should not kill my processes, but I ran out of ideas)
2. In privacy settings [I disabled automatic screen lock](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-screen-lock.html.en) (once again this should not kill my processes)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "Random user logouts" are better known as *crashes*. Look in /var/crash for .crash files. The name of each file will tell you what application crashed each time. Also review your logs to see if those applications are throwing warnings or errors before they crash that you could catch.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for your suggestion. ls -la shows my /var/crash folder is empty.

Comment: Immediately after your "forced logout", login and type the terminal command `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` to see why. Adjust the "`5 minutes`" as necessary..

Comment: I haven't experienced any crashes since I installed Nvidia drivers two days ago (was using nouveau before). Maybe this fixed my problems. Will report back in about a week.

Comment: Changing to Nvidia 510 driver seems to solve the problem, no issues since about a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue:

The solution is to use Nvidia 510 proprietary drivers instead of the xserver-xorg open source drivers.